# Is there a closed sum to the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, bessel-functions, bernoulli-numbers

Came across another interesting sum when trying to use Euler-Maclaurin on the ratio of a geometric series.

Does anyone recognize a closed form to the following?:

$$
\sum_{z=1}\frac{B_{2z}\ x^{2z}}{(2z)!(2z+2m)!}\ s.t. m \in \mathbb N = ???
$$

I have some clues, namely:

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html

Also, the idea of Eqtn 42 from: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html
which more information on can be found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: I think that  does not have finite closed-form expression in terms of very large class of special functions, for $m=0$ is $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } 4 \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{4 k \pi }\right)=?$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk you can simplify the square of a sine so I think your expression does actually have a closed form

Comment: @mick. Impossible.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk oh I misread. You are probably right, sorry. +1